# Problems installing Julia package using JuliaPro

Tags: package, julia

I am very new to the Julia programming language. I have tried installing packages but none of my attempts were successful thus far.

For example, I ran the command:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("JuMP")
```

I end up getting the error:

```
The following package names could not be resolved:
 * JuMP (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

This happens for any package I try to install. I also tried entering ] add JuMP but this did not work either. Here is a screenshot of all the error details.

[image]

Edit:
When I run Pkg.Status() I get

```
Status `C:\Users\ndook\.julia\environments\JuliaPro_v1.5.1-1\Project.toml`
  [c52e3926] Atom v0.12.21 ⚲
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.21.3
  [e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.8.3 ⚲
  [4722fa14] PkgAuthentication v0.3.0
  [44d3d7a6] Weave v0.10.3
```

Comment: try : `Pkg.add("JuMP")`

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: What `Pkg.status()` gives you ?

Comment: I edited the question to show the results of Pkg.status()

Comment: remove the `.julia` folder and run `Pkg.init()` and try installing the package again

Comment: Which .julia folder are you referring to and how exactly do I remove it?

Comment: That folder : `C:\Users\ndook\.julia`

Comment: From looking at the [JuliaPro website](https://juliacomputing.com/products/juliapro/), it seems like JuliaPro comes with two separate package registries: the General registry and a JuliaPro curated registry. JuMP is not in the JuliaPro curated registry. There might be a way to switch the registry that you are using. Otherwise, I would recommend installing the generic Julia application. The Windows installer for Julia can be found [here](https://julialang.org/downloads/).

Comment: The problem was solved by first running `rm(joinpath(homedir(), ".julia", "registries"); recursive=true)`

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the fix for this issue is to run: `rm(joinpath(homedir(), ".julia", "registries"); recursive=true)`. If you counintue to run into issues with JuliaPro, please open an issue here: https://github.com/JuliaComputing/JuliaProIssues